# Condensing a list of events into containers by hour, including "blank" containers (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Say I have a list of events ranging over several weeks that are stored as hashes, each with a `DateTime` `:date` key.

Is there any way I can turn this into an array of events, grouped by their hour.  That is, the first entry is for events in hour #1, the second entry being for events in hour #2, etc.

Sample list of events:

```
e = [ { :date => (DateTime), :name => "event 1" },
      { :date => (DateTime), :name => "event 2" } ]
```

At first I was enumerating through all of the hours in the date range, and adding the ones that match into the array as I go through the hours.  But this seems very non-ruby-like to me.

I have found the `Enumerable#group_by` method, but this only creates the hour "containers" that have events in them and none that are skipped.

Is there a clean functional approach to this problem?  If not, is there an elegant and ruby-like way instead?

Also, what about grouping them by *pairs* of hours instead?  As in, groups of two hours.  Or an arbitrary number of hours per group.

Comment: Can you provide a sample hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516) method is your friend, if `h` contains DateTime keys and events as values, then:

```
h = {
    DateTime.new('2011-06-03 12:34')    => 'event one',
    DateTime.new('2011-06-11 22:00:00') => 'event two'
}
a = h.each_with_object(Array.new(24) { [] }) { |(k,v), a| a[k.hour - 1].push(v) }
# a is now [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ["event one"], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ["event two"], [], []]
```

And you'll end up with 24 entries in `a`, each entry will be an array, and the non-empty ones will contain the events. You'll want to use the block form of `Array.new` so that you get distinct arrays as the default values.

And if you want to group the hours into two hour spans:

```
a = h.each_with_object(Array.new(12) { [] }) { |(k,v), a| a[((k.hour - 1) / 2).to_i].push(v) }
# a is now [[], [], [], [], [], ["event one"], [], [], [], [], ["event two"], []]
```

And then you can convert the indices of `a` to time ranges on output with little effort.

Further generalizations are left as an exercise for the reader.

If you're stuck with 1.8 and you're not in a Rails environment, then you can get the same results with [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494):

```
h.inject(Array.new(24) { [ ] }) { |a, (k,v)| a[k.hour - 1].push(v); a }
```

But the argument order for the block is different and the block has to return the array.

Comment: each_with_object is available in 1.9.2 without Rails (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516).

Comment: @steenslag: Hence the "If you're stuck with **1.8** or you're not in a Rails environment" and the link in the first sentence. Did I miss something? Or perhaps that bit could have been a bit clearer.

Comment: @steenslag: I replaced the "1.8 or you're" with "1.8 and you're". Does that work better? I think it does.